# Why do things which attach to the 連用形 of 動詞 attach to the stem of 形容詞?

Tags: grammar, verbs, suffixes, i-adjectives, renyōkei

When you want to connect a 活用語 (inflectable word) to something else, generally you inflect it to the 連用形 (continuative form). However, with 形容詞 (i-adjectives), there are certain times where you affix things to the 語幹 (stem) as opposed to the 連用形.

**〜そう** (Affixes to 連用形 for 動詞, but 語幹 for 形容詞.)

> 動詞：　降りそう＝「降る」の連用形＋「そう」
>   形容詞：おいしそう＝「おいしい」の語幹＋「そう」

**〜すぎる** (Affixes to 連用形 for 動詞, but 語幹 for 形容詞.)

> 動詞：　食べすぎる＝「食べる」の連用形＋「すぎる」
>   形容詞：高すぎる＝「高い」の語幹＋「すぎる」

My guess is that these suffixes want something "noun-like", and since the 連用形 of 形容詞 is adverbial, it doesn't work and instead the stem ended up serving that function.

But, this is just a guess, so I'd like to know if anyone has a historical explanation of some of these things, or more examples to make that argument sound more convincing.

Comment: Note that this occurs not only with suffixes, e.g. 早起き (unless you want to convince yourself that 起き is a verb-derived suffix).

Answer (score 4):

The linguist Kunio Nishiyama analyzes the 連用形 of a verb as its stem, plus an epenthetic vowel `-i` in the case of consonant-stem verbs.  This makes sense because:

1. It appears with consonant-stem verbs, e.g. between the root `hur-` and the suffix `-sou` (振りそう).
2. It does not appear with vowel-stem verbs, e.g. between the root `mi-` and the suffix `-sou` (見そう).
3. It does not appear with -i adjectives, e.g. between the root `taka-` and the suffix `-sou` (高そう).

In other words, all three of these cases can be described as the suffix attaching to the root.  The epenthetic `-i` is inserted in cases where Japanese requires that a consonant be followed by a vowel.

I'm not sure where Nishiyama presents this idea formally.  I read about it in a footnote in his workshop paper [*Japanese Verbal Morphology in Coordination*](http://conf.ling.cornell.edu/WOSA/Nishiyama_handout.pdf) (2012) while I was trying to research a different topic.  If you read through that handout, you can see some of the consequences of this analysis.

Comment: Just my two cents: I agree that Nishiyama’s analysis is spot on when analyzing the cases of the current question, but I am not sure if it is a good idea to analyze all uses of 連用形 of a verb that way.  For example, if we compare 連用中止法 of verbs and i-adjectives, the latter really require 連用形 instead of just the stem (e.g., ジョンは強く優しい).  Therefore it seems more logical to me to consider 学び in 学びそう/学びすぎる (stem with epenthesis) and 学び in よく学びよく遊ぶ (true 連用形) as two theoretically different things, which happen to take the same form in case of verbs.

Comment: I feel like this answer doesn't really get to the core of what I was asking (though it certainly gets part of the way there). I very much like @TsuyoshiIto's point. I'd guess the "stem with epenthesis" is what has the noun-like properties, allowing it to be used with these suffixes and in noun compounds (like Earthling pointed out), while the 連用形 is what allows for the 中止法 and just normal verb+aux-verb compounding.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Well, I can analyze the word 優しい as having the stem `yasasik-`...so the epenthetic vowel is /u/.

Comment: @user54609: I am afraid that that explanation does not make sense.  If the stem of 優しい is yasasik-, how do you explain 優し in 優しそう/優しすぎる?  The reason I suggested to distinguish the stem possibly with epenthetic -i (e.g. 学び in 学びそう/学びすぎる and 優し in 優しそう/優しすぎる) and the true 連用形 form (e.g. 学び and 優しく used in 中止法) in the first place is that they are different in case of adjectives.

Comment: Hmm. I have never considered 優しく to be a true 連用形 in itself, mostly because it is syntactically an adverb, and verb 連用形s don't act like adverbs. It does act similar to a 連用形 in the specific place you mentioned though...

Comment: @user54609: (1) I am not sure what you mean by “it [優しく] is syntactically an adverb.”  For example, I do not think that we can treat 優しく in ジョンは優しく強い syntactically as an adverb.  If it is not clear, I think that it becomes clearer with different subjects: ジョンは優しく、ポールは強い.  (2) 中止法 is not the only place where what I called the true 連用形 appears.  Another place is before particle て, although it causes sound changes in case of consonant-stem verbs: 学んで (< 学びて), 見て, 優しくて, and so on.

Comment: Hmm...I guess my Japanese just sucks then, as I never knew `ジョンは優しく、ポールは強い` was possible. I was under the impression that you needed `ジョンは優しくて、ポールは強い`. I always parsed `ジョンは優しく強い` as "John is nicely strong", as 形容詞 act like verbs in final position, just as I could say `ジョンは大きく泣いている`.

Comment: Also, apparently a number of linguists interestingly seem to treat the て sound-change form as a fake 連用形 due to Japanese people stubbornly applying outdated terms, and prefer to call the -i form, which you call an epenthetic vowel, the 連用形 or `conjugative form`. Those people would analyze 遊んで as `|asob.te|`. I'm not sure which theory I believe in though, seems like quabbling about semantics. Which form is more "continuative"? :)

Comment: @user54609: (1) 優しく強い means “kind and strong,” and I do not think that we can consider 優しく modifies 強い.  It is true that 連用形 of adjectives sometimes modifies verbs or adjectives: 優しく抱く and 著しく強い, although 著しく is probably often considered as an adverb derived from 著しい.  If we treat 著しく in 著しく強い as adjective, the syntactic distinction between 優しく強い (two predicates put side by side) and 著しく強い (the first modifies the second) only comes from semantics.

Comment: (2) I am not sure what the best way to call the form before て is, but if 遊んで and 優しくて are treated as the stem (asob-/yasasik-) + epenthetic -u- inserted sometimes + te, I am not sure how to call 優し in 優しそう.  Also “inserted sometimes” seems a little unsatisfactory.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto て was historically an aux. verb (the 連用形 of -tu), so it attaching to the 連用形 of verbs and adjectives certainly makes sense.

Comment: @Darius Jahandarie: Thanks for the information.  I think that there is no controversy to call the form before て as 連用形 when we take the historical point of view, but my understanding of user54609’s comments is that some linguists do not like that point of view, and in particular they do not like to treat 遊んで as “just” a sound variation of 遊びて.  It is in that case that I do not know what to call the form before て.

Comment: I am afraid that we went too long in comments of snailboat’s answer, so I will shut up here.